# WPF toolkit DataGrid show fields even with browsable attribute set to false

Tags: c#, wpf, attributes, browsable

Hi have an observable collection that I bind to a DataGrid using the itemsource property of the DataGrid.

All the properties of the class inside the collection are displayed properly in the DataGrid. Now, I want to hide some fields to the DataGrid using the browsable attribute [Browsable(false)] in the class. It works well in winforms, but it seems not working in WPF.

Someone knows why? I can hide the columns later, but I don't want to loss performance in this way.

Is there any other solution?

Thanks.

Comment: +1 I'd like an answer to this as well.

Comment: The workaround below is OK, if you need it 100 times you might have to subclass WPF datagrid (otherwise you have to hook up the function on every grid you use).

Comment: +1 I'd also like to know why this is the case, and if there's a better way around it than just cancelling it in the AutoGeneratingColumn event

Answer (score 12):

This code works in .NET 4.0

```
void m_grid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (((PropertyDescriptor)e.PropertyDescriptor).IsBrowsable == false)
       e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would be nice to be able to set member attributes and have them respected by .NET 4.0 DataGrid.

Answer (score 1):

the **DisplayAttribute** [msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) seems to work for the silverlight toolkit. I have not tried it in WPF but they are often the same.