# Why Browsable(false) does not hide columns in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, datagrid

In my WPF apllication I want to hide column in DataGrid with binding ItemsSource  by adding [Browsable(false)] to some properties
But, with or without Browsable(false) all columns are visible.

My model:

```
public class Room : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int id;
  ...
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.id;
        }
        set
        {
            this.id = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }
    ...
    public Room()
    {
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChangedEventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChangedEventHandler != null)
        {
            propertyChangedEventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

View:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Rooms}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRoom, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

How can I use Browsable(false) to hide columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, I'm afraid. The `Browsable` attribute only affects the Properties view of the visual designer, it has NO effect during runtime...

For more info, check the [MSDN page about BrowsableAttribute.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can hide them by hooking up the AutoGeneratingColumn Event on your DataGrid (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3794324/4735446).

```
public class DataGridHideBrowsableFalseBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.AutoGeneratingColumn += AssociatedObject_AutoGeneratingColumn;
        base.OnAttached();
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((PropertyDescriptor)e.PropertyDescriptor).IsBrowsable == false)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
}


<DataGrid
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataGridSource, Mode=OneWay}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="true">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:DataGridHideBrowsableFalseBehavior>
             </behaviors:DataGridHideBrowsableFalseBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't call `this.OnPropertyChanged("Id");` in your code.